# "Awesome" vs. "Awful"

Tags: etymology

How did the English language come to this?

> The play was awful.

Is the complete opposite of

> The play was awesome.

But if you break it down to **awe** followed by **ful** or **some**, it doesn't make sense at all.
Can someone shed a light on this?  Is there a rule to this, or is it one of those things you need to just memorize?

Comment: The answer is quickly gotten from google search and has to do "awe" historically having a meaning closer to "fear" and "dread", but I'm a bit too lazy to write it up properly. Incidentally, this reminds me of "priceless" vs. "worthless".

Comment: Neither bearing an outsourced opinion nor a linguist of any definition, @MitchSchwartz, but seems to me that "priceless" deals with the cost of a thing, i.e. something that must be paid in order to have the thing. Even though that thing has no cost, it definitely has worth. Price and worth are surely not the same thing? One is commodity value and the other is personal value (at least if used without additional context?). Question compares dissimilar suffixes with similar meaning and same base, you compare same suffixes and meaning with different base. What is the reminder? [citationneeded] ;)

Comment: @MitchSchwartz The irony of your comment is that StackOverflow most often ends up at the top of those Google results soon after the question is asked. In fact, that is exactly how I arrived at this page.

Comment: I have the same confusion about meaning>meaningful, wonder>wonderful, fear>fearful, and dread>dreadful. It seems like there are some deriver forms that oppose the rule and logic.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The words have been around hundreds and hundreds of years.  While they were constructed by combining *awe* with *-ful* or *-some*, once they became lexical items as complete words, their meaning was able to drift like any other lexical item — the fact that each word is composed of a stem and suffix doesn't stop this.  (Also, bear in mind that *-some*, the suffix, doesn't mean "some of X", it means "having the quality of X".  Think *fearsome*, *loathsome*, *cumbersome*.  And *-ful* is basically the same as *-some* in its meaning, with all words.)

Originally, *awful* had the meaning of being awe-inspiring (including positive connotations), as well as "worthy of, or commanding, profound respect or reverential fear."  It was not a far stretch to then use it also to mean "Causing dread; terrible, dreadful, appalling."  The earliest records of these uses date back to at least 1000 AD.  Between 1000 and 1800, the word evolved to the current meaning: "Frightful, very ugly, monstrous; and hence as a mere intensive deriving its sense from the context = Exceedingly bad, great, long, etc."

*Awesome* came around much later than *awful*.  It is first recorded in 1598, after *awful* had been around hundreds of years.  Perhaps the need for this word arose because *awful* had already taken on such a strong negative connotation by this time.  So *awesome* stepped in to again have the meaning of "awe-inspiring", but without the strong negative connotations.  Ultimately, in the mid-1900s, the word *awesome* went from *awe-inspiring* to its more common use today: "amazing, great, etc."

So, this is how the words ended up like this.  Yes, you do have to memorize the words to some extent, because they have certain connotations and colloquial meanings that are extremely common. But, again, part of the problem is treating *-some* like *some*.  None of the *-some* words have a connection to the current meaning of *some*.

(All of this data came from the [OED](http://oed.com).)

Comment: But now "awesome" is used so much it could just mean nice...

Comment: We do still say something is _awfully_ good, which presumably heralds back to the older, less negative meaning.

Answer (score 4):

The suffix *-some* indicates the characteristic of the root word. So, "awesome" would be "characterized by awe/awe-inspiring". The suffix *-ful* means "full of/having the qualities of". Really, both suffixes mean the same thing. The word "awful" is an exception, however, in current English. An archaic meaning of "awful", though, is "full of awe/inspiring awe, wonder or fear". Many of examples of this usage can be found in old literature.  The word "awful" aptly described disasters and catastrophes, since they inspired fear and awe, even though they were calamitous. Gradually, that usage crept into modern colloquialism, eventually getting frequently applied to bad things in general.

Comment: Jasper, that's awfully nice of you to say :)

Comment: @Jasper @Jimi -- you guys are awful! jk =)

Comment: @BeemerGuy Awesome could be conceived as something with awe. Like a bike or person without the negative connotation.and intentional opposite meaning that awful inherited.

Answer (score 0):

*Cheerful* and *cheersome* would mean the same thing. 
So did an illogical process make *awful/awesome* antonyms?

In old English, *aue, eghe, ege,* was "fear, terror, great reverence". 
From the Norse *egi*: fright.

It is surprising that by the 1600's, awesome was used to describe prayer and devotion, whereas in the 1700's it described doom and gloom.

Awesome is [seldom used in books until the 1850's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aweful%2Cawesome&year_start=1200&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caweful%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cawesome%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Caweful%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cawesome%3B%2Cc0)
[image]

let's see some previous use:

- 1630... His Pipe smoak'd out with aweful Grace
- 1680... The Lord hath made aweful breaches upon
- 1690... It requires the most aweful and reverential frame of our hearts
- 1700 It makes the soul aweful in the discharge of duties of worship
- 1714...  by that Day the Apostle intends that Aweful Day, when Christ shall 
  come in flaming Firey to take Vengeance 
  It renders the soul aweful and solemn in the presence of god
- 1760...  A battle is still a more aweful subject
- 1780...  'but struck with aweful dread * Were hush'd as death
- 1788... visible through the mist, which served to aggravate the gloom of this 
  aweful place

in the 1700's aweful described earthquakes, battles, disasters. Perhaps the 1600's writers had forgotten the original frightful meaning? perhaps a change of pronunciation elicited more gloom in the 17th century?

Given the words "woesome" and "woeful". Everyday use would put a positive spin on  *woesome* compared to *woeful*, because of the moderate nature of the suffixe "some", compared to the excessive "full".

There may also be elements of onomatopoeia, with the "S" and "osam" being preferred over "F" and "oful".

It may have previously been pronounced "ireful" and "hourful". The modern English prefix is so brief that most people don't notice that the two words are related, so the sense can diverge more easily than "cheerful" and "cheersome", which are easier to place semantically.