# How to understand "in and of themselves" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence

> In addition to investigating how financial value is produced,46 such
> scholarship has shown that discourses of financialization cannot, ***in
> and of themselves***, explain the sweeping changes that are happening in
> the global economy.

How to understand ***"in and of themselves"*** in this sentence?

Comment: I don't want to close this question with a single vote, so I will instead ask whether the answers at [What is the reasoning for the idiom "in and of itself" having the meaning it has?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13724/what-is-the-reasoning-for-the-idiom-in-and-of-itself-having-the-meaning-it-has) answer your question. Do they?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the reasoning for the idiom "in and of itself" having the meaning it has?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13724/what-is-the-reasoning-for-the-idiom-in-and-of-itself-having-the-meaning-it-has)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simplify your sentence, you get

> Discourses cannot explain [something] ***in and of themselves***.

The expression here is  ***in and of itself***. According to *[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/in-and-of-itself#:%7E:text=What%20does%20in%20and%20of,phrase%20is%20used%20for%20emphasis.)*,

> ***In and of itself*** is another way of saying “on its own” or “by its very nature.” For example,
>
> *The final book in the series is, **in and of itself**, a great work of
> art.*

Therefore, your simplified sentence could read:

> Discourses cannot explain [something] ***by their very nature*** or ***on their own***.